# How to parse data using curl for more then 20 sites?

Tags: php, wordpress

We made a wordpress plugin to parse some data from other websites. We use curl. But the problem is, curl works for at most 20 sites. We have 29 sites. When we parse 20 sites it doesn't show any problem. But when we parse all 29 sites it shows 504 Gate Time out. How to solve this?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Maybe space out the requests a bit (timewise) so you don't overload anything.

Comment: Increase the max execution time

Comment: Are you using a load balancer? Are you halting page execution when this runs? The 504 is on your instance or one of the sites being crawled?

Comment: @user3783243 504 is showing in my site while parsing.

Comment: Is there a load balancer in play?

Comment: @user3783243 Actually we are using Digital Oceans droplet.  I guess no load balancers.

Answer (score -1):

If one of the site fails (it's not responding) the execution stops there. You should use `try` & `catch` to prevent this scenario. Also increase `max_execution_time` and `memory_limit`.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1200);
ini_set('memory_limit', "1024M");

try {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    $err = curl_error($ch);
    echo $err;
    curl_close($ch);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    print $ex->getMessage();
}
```

If you also use Sunra\PhpSimple\HtmlDomParser, increase the `MAX_FILE_SIZE`:

```
define("MAX_FILE_SIZE", 6000000);
```

It's also possible that you cannot override your `ini` values because of your server settings and the solution is to break the parsing into several separate requests.

Activate all error reporting to investigate the issue better:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Comment: This presumes the issue is on one of the external sites and not the executing site.

Comment: I also added max_execution_time and memory_limit.

Comment: @Valeriu Ciuca, I tried first 20 and then last 9. It doesn't show any problem. When I try all 29 at the same time then the error comes.

Comment: Did you modified your script with the increased values and try and catch? It's also possible that you cannot override you ini settings because of your server settings.

Comment: @ValeriuCiuca, I have just added max execution time, max file size, memory limit and try catch. Still the error is there.

Comment: Activate all error reporting with error_reporting(E_ALL);  I also modified the script with: curl_error for better debugging.

Comment: 504 Gateway Time-out
The server didn't respond in time.
same error as before